# Upload File to Amazon S3 From Angular Client?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload only png files to Amazon S3. This is the architecture of the upload system.

I am stuck with **Step 6** Using Angular.

[image]

**URL Generation Code Looks like [Node JS/ Typescript]**

```
public getWaterMarkURL(payload: any, expiry: number = 20, Bucket: string = SNAP_SENSE_BUCKET_PATH): Promise<any> {
    let validationCheck = this.validateView(payload);
    if (!validationCheck.status) return Promise.reject({...validationCheck, statusCode: 412});
    let Key: string = `watermark/${payload.user_id}/${payload.event_id}/watermark.png`;
    let signedURL: string = this.s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', { Bucket, Key, Expires: expiry * 60, ACL: "public-read" });
    return Promise.resolve({body: {data: { signedURL }}, statusCode: 201 });
  }
```

**File Upload Code Looks like [Angular 8]**

```
let p: Promise<any>[] = [logoIMG.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_PNG), this.generateSignedURL()];

    Promise.all(p).then((respArr: any[]) => {          
      let image: Buffer = respArr[0];
      let url: string = respArr[1];          
      this.http.put(url, image).subscribe(console.log, console.error);
    });
```

---

### Configurations

```
<CORSConfiguration>
      <CORSRule>
          <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
          <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
          <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
          <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
          <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
      </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: are you getting a specific error? Also, it seems wasteful to send a file up to your server once, then again to s3.. just direct the file straight to s3 through your server.

Comment: I am not sending the file twice? and It Says Unknow error.

Comment: your diagram shows 1. client wants to upload this file, implying it is sent to the server first... where does it say unknown error? which part in the chain is giving that error? do you get a proper presigned url back from your server? is it the error handler of the subscribe? what is the status code?

Comment: I am stuck at Step 6. Yes, I do get a signed URL. And the Status code is 200.

Comment: Step1 is the request for signed URL.

Comment: where does it say unknown error? which part in the chain is giving that error?

Comment: Step 6: Gives the unknown error!,

this.http.put(url, image).subscribe(console.log, console.error);

Comment: sigh.... NOT which step in your diagram. which step in your REQUEST

Comment: The Preflight request is successful. Put Request gives the error.